# Working with VB.Net Assemblies

Tags: genexus

It seems that the ".Net Assembly Import" is actually a "C# Assembly Import"...

I am trying to import a VB.Net Assembly (Tools > Application Integration > .Net Assembly Import) only to find that it cannot be done.
I get the error:

> *"Error trying to load Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified."*

I usually don't have problems importing C# Assemblies, so I tried to create an intermediate C# class to access the methods of the Vb.Net one.... But it also seems that I can't import C# assemblies into Gx, when they have a reference to a Vb.Net class.

How can I access the methods of a VB.Net Assembly?

Answer (score 2):

Did you put the vb.net assembly .dll into bin folder of your application?

Theoretically vb.net code and c# code turns into bytecode compiled by .net framework

I found this url that convert´s the code from vb.net to c# and vice versa (if you have the source, if not try decompile)

http://converter.telerik.com/

Hope that helps.

Regards, Felipe.

Comment: Yes, the .dll was placed inside the bin folder, and the error above is shown when I try to "open" it using the Assembly Import wizard. I really think VB.Net assemblies aren't supported. I managed to create a procedure with CSharp code to consume these assemblies with System.Reflection (FilePath and MethodName as parameters).